# Coefficient of friction between 2 surfaces

Tags: friction, material-science, drag

If I have both the kinetic and static coefficients of friction between cardboard and steel and between rubber and steel (for the same steel in both cases), is there a way to find the coefficient between cardboard and rubber? For example, can this be done by equalising the force on cardboard/steel and the force on rubber/steel?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The coefficient of friction is independent of the force with which the surfaces are pressed together, so your suggestion would not make any difference.